# AggregatingMergeTree - Partition field is aggregatable

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table of this form:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dw_ttest
(
    name String,
    partition_id SimpleAggregateFunction(max, UInt32),
    balance SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64)
)
    ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
    PARTITION BY partition_id
    ORDER BY name
```

I need to aggregate by a partition field.
That is, to aggregate across all rows of the table, not just within a partition.
I need the partition itself for convenient search among the data, because there is a lot of data (over a billion rows).
How can I save partitions and still aggregate data by this field?

I can query the table using
`GROUP BY field WITH TOTALS`.
but the table itself is not updated

Comment: Yes, GROUP BY allows me to get the correct data from the table, but I need the aggregation itself to update the partition_id for the name